# Default Value Dropdown AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dropdown, value, default

Em meu projeto eu tenho um dropdown, iterado de uma array.
Notem que na array possuo uma key chamada default que está setada como true ou false.
Gostaria que o defalt value do dropdown fosse o que viesse com a key setada como true.

Se eu fizer isto: `$scope.nfe.naturezaOperacao = $scope.cfops[0];`, funciona, porém, estou definindo estático, gostaria que setasse o padrão de acordo com a chave default.

**JS:**

```
angular.module('nfe', []).controller('nfeController', function ($scope, $http) {

  $scope.nfe = [];

  $scope.cfops = [
    {codigo: "5.102", descricao : "Venda a vista 12%", elo: "012", default: false},
    {codigo: "5.102", descricao : "Venda a vista 17%", elo: "017", default: true}
  ];


  //$scope.nfe.naturezaOperacao = $scope.cfops[0];
});
```

---

**HTML:**

```
<select
 class="form-control"
 name="NF_NATUREZA_OPERACAO"
 id="NF_NATUREZA_OPERACAO"
 data-ng-model="nfe.naturezaOperacao"
 data-ng-init=""
 data-ng-options="cfop.descricao for cfop in cfops">
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considerando que apenas **um** objeto dentro do *array* `cfops` terá a propriedade `default` com o valor `true`, você pode injetar [`$filter`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) no seu controlador e utilizar a primeira posição retornada por essa função (adicionei mais objetos ao *array* para exemplificar o funcionamento):

```js
angular
  .module('nfe', [])
  .controller('nfeController', function ($scope, $http, $filter) {
    $scope.nfe = [];

    $scope.cfops = [
      {codigo: "5.102", descricao : "Venda a vista 12%", elo: "012", default: false},
      {codigo: "5.102", descricao : "Venda a vista 17%", elo: "017", default: true},
      {codigo: "5.102", descricao : "Venda a vista 10%", elo: "010", default: false},
      {codigo: "5.102", descricao : "Venda a vista 11%", elo: "011", default: false},
      {codigo: "5.102", descricao : "Venda a vista 12%", elo: "012", default: false},
      {codigo: "5.102", descricao : "Venda a vista 13%", elo: "013", default: false}
    ];

    $scope.nfe.naturezaOperacao = $filter('filter')($scope.cfops, { default: true })[0];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="nfe" ng-controller="nfeController">
  <select
   class="form-control"
   name="NF_NATUREZA_OPERACAO"
   id="NF_NATUREZA_OPERACAO"
   data-ng-model="nfe.naturezaOperacao"
   data-ng-init=""
   data-ng-options="cfop.descricao for cfop in cfops">
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Desta maneira está incorreto? Qual seria a melhor forma para fazer isso?

```
      /* SETA O CFOP PADRÃO */
      for (var i in $scope.cfops) {
        if ($scope.cfops[i].cfop_padrao == true) {
          $scope.nfe.naturezaOperacao = $scope.cfops[i];
        } else {
          $scope.nfe.naturezaOperacao = $scope.cfops[0];
        }
      }
```

```js
angular
  .module('nfe', [])
  .controller('nfeController', function ($scope, $http, $filter) {
    $scope.nfe = [];

    $scope.cfops = [
      {codigo: "5.102", descricao : "Venda a vista 12%", elo: "012", default: false},
      {codigo: "5.102", descricao : "Venda a vista 17%", elo: "017", default: true},
      {codigo: "5.102", descricao : "Venda a vista 10%", elo: "010", default: false},
      {codigo: "5.102", descricao : "Venda a vista 11%", elo: "011", default: false},
      {codigo: "5.102", descricao : "Venda a vista 12%", elo: "012", default: false},
      {codigo: "5.102", descricao : "Venda a vista 13%", elo: "013", default: false}
    ];

    $scope.nfe.naturezaOperacao = $filter('filter')($scope.cfops, { default: true })[0];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="nfe" ng-controller="nfeController">
  <select
   class="form-control"
   name="NF_NATUREZA_OPERACAO"
   id="NF_NATUREZA_OPERACAO"
   data-ng-model="nfe.naturezaOperacao"
   data-ng-init=""
   data-ng-options="cfop.descricao for cfop in cfops">
  </select>
</div>
```